# Simple program rock paper scissors while loop

Tags: python

This is a basic game just like rock paper scissor but with different names,  I also apologize for the commentless code.  I'm almost getting to the end of my code, but I'm having a tough time with the while loop.  I have all on my statements done, but how do I implement a while loop? I want the game to run again after I finish it so it will ask me for another input.  If I run this, it is waiting to give me an answer, but never does, since it is an infinite loop.

```
import random
def pythonRubyJava():
    gameList = ["python","ruby","java"]
    userInput = raw_input("python, ruby, or java?:")
    randomInput = random.choice(gameList)
    print randomInput
    while True:
        if userInput not in gameList:
            print "The game is over"
        elif userInput == randomInput:
            print "stalemate"
        elif userInput == "python" and randomInput == "ruby":
            print "You win!"
        elif userInput == "ruby" and randomInput == "java":
            print "You win!"
        elif userInput == "java" and randomInput == "python":
            print "You win!"        
        elif userInput == "python" and randomInput == "java":
            print "You Lose!"    
        elif userInput == "ruby" and randomInput == "python":
            print "You Lose!"        
        elif userInput == "java" and randomInput == "ruby":
            print "You Lose!"
```

Comment: Move your `while True:` up to before assigning `userInput`.

Comment: thank you for your help.  I'm a beginner and still getting used to using loops.

Comment: Python loses to Java in your game? That's a bit funny. :)

Comment: @ShashankGupta: Java smothers Python in the smoke of hundreds of factory-factories. Python beats Ruby by having developers in at least two application areas. Ruby beats Java with the pointy end of a NullPointerException.

Comment: @abarnert LOL so true, all Ruby really has is going for it is Ruby on Rails. And yes the pollution of Java factories is quite hard to stand :(

Comment: I think you can refactor this into `if userInput == 'python': print 'You win!'`

Comment: @poke +1 for the brilliant 1-line optimization.

Comment: Haskell is godlike :)

Answer (score 3):

You should move

```
userInput = raw_input("python, ruby, or java?:")
randomInput = random.choice(gameList)
```

inside the `while` loop so that the inputs are regenerated each time the loop is run.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a while loop in the function, just call the function again! Remove the while loop from your function.

Outside the function, you can do something like:

```
pythonRubyJava() # Call the function first
while 1:
    ans = raw_input('Do you want to play again? Y/N ')
    if ans == 'Y':
        pythonRubyJava()
    else:
        print "bye!"
        break # Break out of the while loop.
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but: Recursion should be done in moderation: it's slow, prone to bugs, overflows the stack, ...

Comment: and Python doesn't have proper tail-call elimination like Lua and C++ do :) One of its (very few) downsides.

Comment: Well, Haidro's code doesn't have recursion. However, the way it is written (without saying a thing about how `pythonRubyJava` function is changed) the code doesn't work. The first call never finishes.

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac Oops, I made it a bit more clearer. Thanks for bringing this to my attention

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
def pythonRubyJava():
    gameList = ["python","ruby","java"]
    userInput = raw_input("python, ruby, or java?:")
    randomInput = random.choice(gameList)

    print randomInput
    while True:
        if userInput not in gameList:
            print "The game is over"
            [change the while boolean statement in here]
        elif userInput == randomInput:
            print "stalemate"
        elif userInput == "python" and randomInput == "ruby":
            print "You win!"
        elif userInput == "ruby" and randomInput == "java":
            print "You win!"
        elif userInput == "java" and randomInput == "python":
            print "You win!"        
        elif userInput == "python" and randomInput == "java":
            print "You Lose!"    
        elif userInput == "ruby" and randomInput == "python":
            print "You Lose!"        
        elif userInput == "java" and randomInput == "ruby":
            print "You Lose!"  

 pythonRubyJava():
```

This way it would run again, and show the result.